# Is there a way to render a remote HTML page on the server side, so that it is rendered exactly the way the user would see it in their browser

Tags: javascript, headless-browser, html-rendering

I'm trying to perform structured data validation for remote pages. The user sends a URL, I'm rendering the content on the server with a headless Chrome browser, and returning HTML back to the client to perform the validation. However, as a result of rendering on the different (server) IP address, rendering may be different from what the user sees in their browser (e.g. showing the server's IP instead of the user's IP when rendering the simple [IP check](https://whatismyipaddress.com/), etc.). Is there a way to render the page exactly the way it would appear on the user's device?

Comment: You can't fake an Internet connection. The only ways I can think of is: 1.- The user allows your server to connect through him to load the webpages, though proxies or whatever. 2.- The user loads the webpage using your server as a proxy. 3.- Both the user and you use the very same proxy. Not elegant in any way tho.

Comment: the closest you can do is using [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) but there will always be drawbacks as @JorgeFuentesGonzález mentioned